# Applying a user defined function to a PySpark dataframe and return a dictionary

Tags: pandas, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Suppose I have a pandas dataframe called `df`

```
id value1 value2
1 2 1
2 2 1
3 4 5
```

In plain Python, I wrote a function to process this dataframe and return a dictionary:

```
d = dict()
for row in df.itertuples()
   x = do_something (row)
   d[x[0]] = x[1:]
```

I am trying to reimplement this function using Spark.

```
d = dict() # define a global var
def do_something (id, value1, value2):
   # business logic
   d[x0] = [x1,x2,x3]
   return 0
udf_do = udf (do_something)
```

then:

`df_spark.select (udf_do ('id','value1','value2'))`

My idea is, by calling `df_spark.select`, the function `do_something` will be called over the dataframe, and it will update the global variable `d`. I don't really care about the return value of `udf_do` so I return 0.

My solution does not work, indeed.

Could you suggest me some ways to iterate through (I know it is not a Spark-way) or somehow to process a Spark dataframe and update an external dictionary?

Note that the dataframe is quite large. I tried to convert it to pandas by calling `toPandas()` but I have OOM problem.

Comment: Seems you are looking for something similar to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45881682/8240561)

Answer (score 0):

UDF cannot update any global state. But, you can do some some businness login inside UDF and then use `toLocalIterator` to get all the data to the driver in memory-efficient way (partition by partition). For example:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([(10, 'b'), (20, 'b'), (30, 'c'), 
                            (40, 'c'), (50, 'c'), (60, 'a')], ['col1', 'col2'])
df.withColumn('udf_result', ......)
df.cache()
df.count() # force cache fill

for row in df.toLocalIterator():
    print(row)
```